# CMake error when compiling out of tree model in gnu radio

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, gnuradio

I have a problem and I can't seem to find a solution to it. I am building a project using `gnuradio` and in the process of building an OOT module i always get the following error after `$cmake ../` (I followed the instruction from the GNU site though)

> $ cmake ../
>   -- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
>   -- Could NOT find Boost 
>   CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:63 (message): 
>   Boost required to compile trial
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Please any help will be deeply appreciated (And please I am a noob so kindly have it easy on me).

Comment: Install the boost libraries? How to do this, depends on your OS. On Ubuntu something like `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` should do it. Then run it again.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the debug output for the FindBoost module when invoking cmake, it'll help you pinpoint which packages are missing:

```
$ cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=ON ../
```

Here's a similar problem on kubuntu 14.04: https://github.com/antoinet/gr-acars2/issues/2.
The solution was to install the missing `libboost-filesystem-dev` and `libboost-system-dev` packages.

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue is that 1 or more Boost components (e.g., system, threads, filesystem) is/are not being found, so you need to get it/them installed.  How you do the install depends on your OS.  So ... what OS are you trying to do this on?

Also, how did you install GNU Radio in the first place?  Any package manager with its salt will make sure dependencies are installed correctly along with the actual package.  If you used MacPorts or apt-get or yum to install GNU Radio, Boost should have been installed.

Related: Have you considered signing up for the GNU Radio discussion email list?  This question would be quickly answered there.  https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss-gnuradiosome